Preventing Heads-Up Notifications with IMPORTANCE_HIGH in a Foreground Service
I'm developing an Android application that utilizes a foreground service. To ensure the service remains active, I have set the notification importance to NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH. However, I want to prevent the heads-up notification from appearing to the user.

Is it possible to disable the heads-up notification while keeping the importance at IMPORTANCE_HIGH?

If so, how can this be achieved without affecting the foreground service's ability to stay active?


I am concerned that altering the notification settings might impact the stability or persistence of the foreground service. Any insights or suggestions on how to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
For your information, the targetSdk is 34.
I have tried to lower the importance of notifications to IMPORTANCE_DEFAUT, but I am concerned that the foreground service will be removed because it is pushed by other important tasks.

Per the docs a foreground service requires a notification - you cannot disable or avoid that. On Android versions 33+ the user can dismiss the notification (that was not possible before).
The notification is there to let the user know that your app is performing work even when it is in the background.

Thank you for your answer, does that mean head up is essential?
